# Best (or correct) approach on finding characteristic polynomial of this $4 \times 4$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, characteristic-polynomial

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ be a linear transformation with matrix representation

\begin{align*}
    A = \begin{pmatrix}
        -5 & -5 & -9 & 7 \\ 
        8 & 9 & 18 & -9 \\ 
        -2 & -3 & -7 & 4 \\ 
        0 & 0 & 0 & 2
    \end{pmatrix} 
.\end{align*}

I was requested to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $f$. I should add I'm fairly new to this concept. In any case, I have no theoretical problem with it. What I'm having trouble with is the actual computations, specially for transformations over $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n > 3$, where things get complicated computationally.

Observe the matrix $A-xI$,

\begin{align*}
    A = \begin{pmatrix}
        -5-x & -5 & -9 & 7 \\ 
        8 & 9-x & 18 & -9 \\ 
        -2 & -3 & -7-x & 4 \\ 
        0 & 0 & 0 & 2-x
    \end{pmatrix} 
.\end{align*}

Usually, when calculating the determinant of matrices of this form, I prefer a direct application of the properties of the determinant as an $n$-linear function, looking for ways to factor expressions involving $x$ out of the matrix and thus arriving at an already factorized form of the characteristic polynomial ---which on its turn readily reveals the eigenvalues of the transformation. However, on this particular matrix, I had no success with such procedure.

Of course one could also use the recursive definition of the determinant and decompose $\det(A)$ into

$$(-5-x)\det(A(1|1)) - 8\det(A(2|1))  -2\det(A(3|1))$$

However, this is not necessarily simpler. Hence, I come for practical advice. People more experienced with the topic might have a sense of what is the most practical or straightforward way to compute the characteristic polynomial. Of course I contemplate the possibility that there isn't a more straightforward way than the ones mentioned above. However, since I'm preparing for an exam, I do think it's worth asking for "neater" --less error-prone-- procedures.

Comment: I think that in this case the easiest way would be to use what you call "recursive definition of the determinant" (aka. Laplace expansion) but to use it for the last row instead of the first column. That gives  $\det(A-xI) = (2-x) \det((A-xI)(4|4))$ and reduces the problem to calculating just one $3 \times 3$ derivative.

Comment: @Lukas Your comment is exactly what I was looking for. You should make it an answer; perhaps for you it was simply a trivial observation, but it certainly addressed my question fully! Thanks!!